# C# How to set proxy for all https requstest

Tags: c#, web, proxy

Is it possible to add to the entire application written in C # used a proxy.
Mainly because of the class I pasted below. But I also use several times the usual WebRequest.

I would like the program to use the proxy for each connection that will perform. Is it possible?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace TestV.1.0
{




    // To jest stworzenie klasy HttpHandler, dzieki której możemy pracować na http. Dziedziczy ona z klasy WebClient
    internal class HttpHandler : WebClient
    {
        //Tworzenie obiektu który będzie przechochowywał cookiesy
        public CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _container;
            }
            return request;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            var response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            if (response != null)
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(response.ResponseUri.Scheme, response.ResponseUri.Host);
                _container.SetCookies(uriBuilder.Uri, _container.GetCookieHeader(request.RequestUri));
            }
            return response;
        }

        public void ClearCookies()
        {
            _container = new CookieContainer();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Something like setting [Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the defaultProxy to be used in the `Web.config` or `App.config` of your application.

Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Short answer: You can set this in your global configuration file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy
              proxyaddress="http://192.168.1.10:3128"
              bypassonlocal="false" />
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
<configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Default proxy for all WebRequest with [this static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/", false);
```